# CoreBluetooth XPC Connection Invalid on dismiss viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

After I have finished disconnecting from my bluetooth devices, seeing that they have disconnected in the didDisconnectPeripheral delegate, I attempt to dismiss my viewcontroller.

When this happens I see the message: "[CoreBlueooth] XPC Connection Invalid"

Is there something in specific that has to be cleaned up with Bluetooth before the viewcontroller is dismissed?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the view controller. I get this message every time CBCentralManager gets deallocated. Simply test with a local variable, e.g. CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: nil). As soon as the scope ends, that error message pops up.

Comment: I had the same error ( "[CoreBlueooth] XPC Connection Invalid")... in my case I was instantiating CBCentralManager outside of a view controller. Instantiating it in a view controller solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 11):

I placed `CBCentralManager` to a singleton and the error message is solved.

(`CBCentralManager` will not be deallocated)

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to solve my issue. You can make the CBCentralManager as a class variable (declare it outside the function) instead of local variable.

Comment: I had a similar problem, in my app I have a first screen where BLE devices are listed and when you click on one device, you are bring to another screen and I had this descriptiveness error message. The CBCentralManager is a singleton you have to pass from view to view...

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the following message:

> [CoreBlueooth] XPC Connection Invalid

And I wasn't able to scan BLE devices using a quite simple implementation of the following:

```objective-c
NSObject<CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
```

The solution for me was to add a value in my `Info.plist` for **Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description** `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` describing what I do with Bluetooth Peripheral.

Looks like this in `info.plist`:

```xml
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>Play with BLE Compatible devices<string>
```

*Write something more accurate in here* ;)

Comment: When things like that happens, try to **isolate your problem** so you can identify what makes it fail. You may also comment here with more details. There are plenty of open source projects out there that scans for devices and even lets you write to `characteristics`, etc. [chenee/DarkBlue](https://github.com/chenee/DarkBlue) was helpful to me. For swift projects: [Pluto-Y/Swift-LightBlue](https://github.com/Pluto-Y/Swift-LightBlue). In my case, I started a blank project and did the minimal code to communicate with my device, had to add `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` and it worked 

Comment: @VineeshTP Can you elaborate? As I commented above, isolate your problem and find what's causing this.

Comment: @PravinS. try isolating your problem in a separate project, refer to this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880346/corebluetooth-xpc-connection-invalid-on-dismiss-viewcontroller/45983152?noredirect=1#comment80604835_45983152 feel free to add details or error message you may be getting here. This solution worked for me and still works on an application in production right now ;)

Comment: @Oscar: Actually I don't remember, it is 2 years back. Could you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: I'm getting "[CoreBlueooth] XPC Connection Invalid", which was the original topic here. I've tried another project, a demo project by someone else, and it produces the same message in the console.

Answer (score 4):

CBCentralManager reference should be a strong reference to the class as a member variable. It cannot work as a local reference.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
CBPeripheral *mConnectedPeripheral;

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:mConnectedPeripheral];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happened when I moved all my BLE methods to dedicated class (BLEController) and keep ViewController clean. First I tried to initialize it inside ViewController class like this:

```
let _ = BLEController()
```

This leads to "XPC Connection invalid" issue. What really helped is to move the object to AppDelegate class. To be honest I have no idea why it helped and what is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ran into that problem and after trying to add the necessary key to the Info.plist it still did worked and I had no view to use at this point (it was in the AppDelegate).
So if it still don't work for you try the following.

I used to use: (in Swift)

```
_ = BluetoothMngr.init(config: bleConfig)
```

The problem here was that the variable managing the Bluetooth was not retained so when we add BLE callback these one ended up in an empty class, so simply create a global variable where it's gonna be retained (this is why it works with singleton and view these are retained) like this.

```
self.bleMngr = BluetoothMngr.init(config: bleConfig)
```

Worked for me, hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I turned off app sandbox from capabilities, and it worked